# Runtime of algorithm that calculcates y^(3^n)

Tags: runtime

Given the algorithm,

```
 y := 3
 for i = 1,...,n:
    y := y * y * y
 return y
```

I would like to determine its runtime. I think the algorithm simply calculates y^(3^n). But this doesn't have anything to do with the runtime, right? I think the runtime is determined by n, it would be O(n). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  It is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a multiplication ( `x * x` ) is `O(1)`, then the complexity for your code is `O(n)`.  That's what you will get if `y` in your code is represented using a machine integer.

But the problem is that `x * x` will overflow for large enough `x` if you use machine integers.  In this case, it means that the code won't compute the correct value of `y^(3^n)` except for very small values of `n` and `y`.

To get a correct answer for larger values, you need to use a "big integer" (or [arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)) representation.  For such representations, `x * x` is NOT a `O(1)` operation any more.  It is actually `O(log(x).log(x))` ...

I will leave it to you to estimate the complexity of the entire computation if you use a "big integer" representation.